# Pytransitions: AsyncMachine Sequential Resolution of Asynchronous Dependent Callbacks

Tags: pytransitions

**Note:**
This question is related to Python's FSM library [pytransitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions)

I'm looking for a way to resolve method callbacks sequentially when they've been mentioned as a list in **prepare** or/and **before** or/and **after**. I'm using `AsyncMachine` module from `transitions.extensions.asyncio`

**Expected Result:**

`1Done_2Done_3Done`

**Getting:**

`None_3Done`

**A sample code to replicate current situation:**

```py
import asyncio
from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncMachine


class Model:

    STATES = ['A', 'B']
    TRANSITIONS = [
        {'trigger': 'next', 'source': 'A', 'dest': 'B',
            'prepare': ['initialize1', 'initialize2', 'initialize3'], 'before': [], 'after': ['show_attributes']}
    ]

    def __init__(self, name, state='initial'):
        self.name = name
        self.state = state
        self.attribute_1 = None
        self.attribute_2 = None
        self.attribute_3 = None

    async def initialize1(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # This is expensive operation and will take some time.
        self.attribute_1 = '1Done'
        print(f'{self.name} {self.state} -> Initialized1: ', self.attribute_1)

    async def initialize2(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)  # This is expensive operation and will take some time.
        self.attribute_2 = f'{self.attribute_1}_2Done'
        print(f'{self.name} {self.state} -> Initialized2: ', self.attribute_2)

    async def initialize3(self):
        self.attribute_3 = f'{self.attribute_2}_3Done'
        print(f'{self.name} {self.state} -> Initialized3: ', self.attribute_3)

    async def show_attributes(self):
        print(f'{self.name} {self.state} -> Showing all: {self.attribute_3}')


machine = AsyncMachine(
    model=None,
    states=Model.STATES,
    transitions=Model.TRANSITIONS,
    initial=None,
    queued='model'
    # queued=True
)


async def main():
    model1 = Model(name='Model1', state='A')
    machine.add_model(model1, initial=model1.state)
    await machine.dispatch('next')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

As it's been shown in the code `'prepare': ['initialize1', 'initialize2', 'initialize3']` I'm looking for a way to call initialize2 once initialize1 is resolved and initialize3 once both initialize1 and initialize2 methods are resolved. **Currently, they've been called parallelly which is a good feature but it would be awesome if there is a way to make them execute/resolve in sequence.**

Of course, I can add one more method like `initialize_all` and then call all the above methods inside it. But think about how many new methods I've to keep adding to deal with real-world problems. I want to make my functions reusable and smaller just for a specific task.

Answer (score 2):

**I went through [pytransitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions) source code and I found two ways to achieve the feature I was looking for**.

<sub>I think it would be nice if I mention how I achieved the feature I was looking for.</sub>

Since I was looking for a way to have an asynchronous resolution of callback events (which is by default) and **sequential resolution as per the requirement**, I had to override the `callbacks` method of `AsyncMachine`.

**Method 1:**

```py
import asyncio
from functools import partial
from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncMachine


class EnhancedMachine(AsyncMachine):

    async def callbacks(self, funcs, event_data):
        """ Overriding callbacks method:
            Get `parallel_callback` keyword argument to decide whether
            callback events should be resolved in parallel or in sequence.
        """
        parallel_callback = event_data.kwargs.get('parallel_callback', None)
        resolved_funcs = [partial(event_data.machine.callback, func, event_data) for func in funcs]
        if parallel_callback is False:
            for func in resolved_funcs:
                await func()
        else:
            await self.await_all(resolved_funcs)


class Model:

    STATES = ['A', 'B']
    TRANSITIONS = [
        {'trigger': 'next', 'source': 'A', 'dest': 'B',
            'prepare': ['initialize1', 'initialize2', 'initialize3'], 'before': [], 'after': ['show_attributes']}

    ]

    def __init__(self, name, state='initial'):
        self.name = name
        self.state = state
        self.sequential_transition = True
        self.attribute_1 = None
        self.attribute_2 = None
        self.attribute_3 = None

    async def initialize1(self, ed):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # This is expensive operation and will take some time.
        self.attribute_1 = '1Done'
        print(f'{self.name} {self.state} -> Initialized1: ', self.attribute_1)

    async def initialize2(self, ed):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)  # This is expensive operation and will take some time.
        self.attribute_2 = f'{self.attribute_1}_2Done'
        print(f'{self.name} {self.state} -> Initialized2: ', self.attribute_2)

    async def initialize3(self, ed):
        self.attribute_3 = f'{self.attribute_2}_3Done'
        print(f'{self.name} {self.state} -> Initialized3: ', self.attribute_3)

    async def show_attributes(self, ed):
        print(f'{self.name} {self.state} -> Showing all: {self.attribute_3}')


machine = EnhancedMachine(
    model=None,
    states=Model.STATES,
    transitions=Model.TRANSITIONS,
    initial=None,
    send_event=True,  # this will pass EventData instance for each method.
    queued='model'
    # queued=True
)


async def main():
    model1 = Model(name='Model1', state='A')
    machine.add_model(model1, initial=model1.state)

    # Passing `parallel_callback` as False for synchronous events
    await machine.dispatch('next', parallel_callback=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

**Drawbacks:**

1. `send_event=True` is added and all the method definitions have been added with extra argument `ed` (event_data) to handle the `parallel_callback` keyword argument.
2. Transition callback requires passing `parallel_callback=False` and has to change all possible places in the code.
3. If the next transition has to be decided from the definition of the transition itself, then the keyword argument `parallel_callback` can not be passed (at least I'm not sure how to do this):

   ```
   TRANSITIONS = [
       {'trigger': 'next', 'source': 'A', 'dest': 'B',
           'prepare': [], 'before': [], 'after': ['next2']},
       {'trigger': 'next2', 'source': 'B', 'dest': 'C',
        'prepare': ['initialize1', 'initialize2', 'initialize3'], 'before': [], 'after': ['show_attributes']}
   ]
   ```

**Method 2 (I personally prefer this way):**

In the definition of transitions, grouping the callbacks together which are dependent on each other and should be resolved sequentially.

**Using this method, final transitions would look something like this**:

```
TRANSITIONS = [
    {'trigger': 'next', 'source': 'A', 'dest': 'B',
     'prepare': [('initialize1', 'initialize2', 'initialize3')], 'before': [],
     'after': ['show_attributes']}
]
```

**Explanation:**

`'prepare': [('callback1', 'callback2'), 'callback3']`

Here group1 (callback1 and callback2), group2 (callback3) will be resolved asynchronously (parallelly). But callback1 and callback2 in group1 will be resolved synchronously (sequentially).

**Overriden `callbacks` method will look slightly different now along with a new static method `await_sequential`:**

```py
class EnhancedMachine(AsyncMachine):

    async def callbacks(self, func_groups, event_data):
        """ Triggers a list of callbacks """
        resolved_func_groups = []
        for funcs in func_groups:
            if isinstance(funcs, (list, tuple)):
                resolved_funcs = [partial(event_data.machine.callback, func, event_data) for func in funcs]
            else:
                resolved_funcs = [partial(event_data.machine.callback, funcs, event_data)]
            resolved_func_groups.append(resolved_funcs)

        # await asyncio.gather(*[self.await_sequential(funcs) for funcs in resolved_func_groups])
        await self.await_all([partial(self.await_sequential, funcs) for funcs in resolved_func_groups])

    @staticmethod
    async def await_sequential(funcs):
        return [await func() for func in funcs]
```

**Cons:**

1. Nothing changed in the definition of the methods and the method calls.
2. Changed one place and it fixed all the places.

**Drawbacks:**

1. You should be aware of what your methods are doing. Sometimes unwanted grouping will cause unnecessary delays in the resolution of the events.

**Using both ways, I got the same desired output:**

```
Model1 A -> Initialized1:  1Done
Model1 A -> Initialized2:  1Done_2Done
Model1 A -> Initialized3:  1Done_2Done_3Done
Model1 B -> Showing all: 1Done_2Done_3Done
```

**I'm sticking with the 2nd approach though I'd be happy to know other efficient ways to implement such a feature :)**

Answer (score 1):

I think your 'method 2' looks alright. If you know that all callbacks should be executed sequentially and you do not need parallel execution at all, you could also just override `await_all` with:

```py
class EnhancedMachine(AsyncMachine):

    @staticmethod
    async def await_all(callables):
        return [await func() for func in callables]
```

If you switch the meaning of tuples/lists, you could shorten the code a bit to something like this:

```py
class EnhancedMachine(AsyncMachine):

    async def callbacks(self, func_groups, event_data):
        results = []
        for funcs in func_groups:
            if isinstance(funcs, (list, tuple)):
                results.extend(await self.await_all(
                  [partial(event_data.machine.callback, func, event_data)
                   for func in funcs]
                ))
            else:
                results.append(await self.callback(funcs, event_data))
        return results
```

This enables callback annotation like `[stage_1, (stage_2a, stage_2b, stage_2c), stage_3]` where each stage is sequentially executed but sub-stages are called in parallel.